# office.js dialog api fail to messageParent in IE11 on Win7 and Win8.1

Tags: office-js, office365api, office-addins, office365-apps

I tried to use dialog api for AD authenticating in Office add-in. I try to send message parent and it works well in Chrome but not in IE 11.

Here is same problem described detail: https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/beware-the-dialog-api-falling-silent-under-ie11

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can use websockets to do the messaging for you. I acknowledge this no easy fixup/workaround.

Comment: Let me pass this along to the team.

Comment: We are looking into this, thanks for the heads up

Comment: We have tried the add-in in our environment and it works well in IE 11. Could you contact ruoyingl@microsoft.com so that we can get more information to investigate?

Comment: There is indeed an issue with IE11 on Win7 and Win8.1 that is preventing us from using postMessage (which is what we use under the covers) on those environments. We are following up with the IE team on that.

Comment: Update: We are evaluating a couple of different alternatives to solve this issue. Don't have an ETA to share yet but this is high priority for us

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer. Yes, this is indeed an issue with the API. On IE11 on Win8.1 and Win7 postMessage doesn't work as it should due some restrictions in IE11. The fix was to switch the implementation when running on those versions of IE11 to use localStorage and localStorage events. The fix has already rolled to production for Word/Excel/PPT online. For Outlook online the fix is on its way.